# How to update Textview of an DialogFragment from another Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

First Fragment RequestDialog

when I called function request_services_change by same class is working fine but when call by FragmentB is a null pointer and request_services is empty on debugger

```
 public void RequestDialog(Context context) {

        this.listener = listener;
    }


 public RequestDialog()
    {

    }

  public void request_services_change()
    {
                    Log.d("Text","Request Dailog First Fragment ");// this is working fine from called by same class or Fragment B
        request_services.setText("hello from test 2"); // is called by same class is working fine but when call by FragmentB is null pointer and request_services is empty on debuger 
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_request_dailoge, container, true);
         request_services = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.services_request);

        return this.view;
    }
```

Fragment FragmentB

```
private RequestDialog listener;
public FragmentB () {
    this.listener=new RequestDialog();
}

public function Test()
{
   listener.View_request_services();
}
```

Comment: check whether there is a view id `services_request` in `R.layout.add_request_dailoge`.

Comment: There are libraries that handle this.. Check out EventBus at https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: @Taslim oh nice library is working fine thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there are a bunch of *other ways* to do this but a particular library works just fine for me:  **[Event bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)**.

Event bus facilitates and simplifies communication between Activities, Fragments, Threads, Services, etc. In your case, you can use this library to update the TextView of your DialogFragment (even from another fragment).

It also has extra features like delivery threads and it is fast and relatively light too. I hope this helps.. Merry coding!